# Communicating TCP with HTTP in Socket.io getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined

Tags: node.js, http, socket.io, client-server, tcp

Trying to communicate TCP server with HTTP server

My TCP port is 4040 and HTTP port is 3000

I am working on passing data received on TCP server to HTTP server

Data received on TCP port is showing on console window and I am trying to pass this data to HTTP by storing data in global var so that I can display it on the webpage.

Thanks :)

server code:

```
enter code here    var http = require('http').createServer(httpHandler);
var net = require('net');
var app = require('express')();         <!-- These are mandatory variables -->
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var sockets = [];
var HOST = 'localhost';
var PORT = 4040;
global.MYVAR = "Hello world";
global.MYVAR2 = "Hello world";
var server = net.createServer();
server.listen(PORT, HOST);
// Keep track of the chat clients
var clients = [];
/**
* http server
*/
function httpHandler (req, res) {
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
    res.writeHead(500);
    return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

res.writeHead(200);
res.end(data);
});
}

app.get('/', function(req, res){           <!-- This sends the html file -->
//send the index.html file for all requests
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');

});

http.listen(3000, function(){    <!-- Tells the HTTP server which port to use -->

  console.log('listening for HTTP on *:3000');   <!-- Outputs text to the console -->
  console.log('listening for TCP on port ' + PORT);
});

<!-- everything below this line is actual commands for the actual app -->

io.on('connection', function(socket) // Opens the socket

{
  socket.on('checkbox1', function(msg){  // Creates an event
     console.log(msg); // displays the message in the console
     MYVAR = msg; // Sets the global variable to be the contents of the message recieved
     for (var i = 0; i < sockets.length; i++) {
      if(sockets[i]) {
        sockets[i].write(MYVAR, 'utf-8');
      }
    }
  });

});


server.on('connection', function(socket){ // Opens the socket for the TCP connection
    sockets.push(socket);
    socket.write(MYVAR, 'utf-8');


    // Handle incoming messages from clients.
    socket.on('data', function (data) {

         broadcast(socket.name + "> " + data, socket);

    });
    // Send a message to all clients
function broadcast(message, sender) {

    MYVAR2 = message;
     console.log(MYVAR2);
     socket.broadcast.emit('updateHeader',MYVAR2); // GETTING ERROR HERE

}
  }).listen(PORT, HOST);
```

index.html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Socket IO Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="h1">Hello World</h1>
<form action="">
<input type='checkbox' onclick='checkbox1(this);'>Checkbox1</label>
</form>

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
 var socket = io();
 var number = 0;

 $(document).ready(function(){
 socket.on('updateHeader',function(data){
 console.log('updateHeader called');
 document.getElementById('h1').innerHTML = data;
 });
 });

 function checkbox1(cb) {
 socket.emit('checkbox1', 'checkbox 1 = ' + cb.checked);
 return false;
 }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to use socket.io [broadcast](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#flag-broadcast) in a [net.Socket](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket) which of course doesn't have that property.

```
server.on('connection', function(socket){ /* ... */ }
```

> When a new TCP stream is established. socket is an object of type
>   net.Socket. Usually users will not want to access this event. In
>   particular, the socket will not emit 'readable' events because of how
>   the protocol parser attaches to the socket. The socket can also be
>   accessed at request.connection.

I don't know exactly what you're trying to achieve, but you can use `io.emit` if you want to send message to all clients.

```
function broadcast(message, sender) {
    MYVAR2 = message;

    //This will emit 'updateHeader' to all socket.io connected sockets
    io.emit('updateHeader', MYVAR2); 

    //The 'socket' you were using here was a net.Socket not a socket.io one.
}
```

Comment: Wow man!God bless you! don't know how to thank you! I was trying this for like two weeks.I am new to node.js.Can you suggest me any good book or site where I can learn socket.io

Comment: You're welcome! I learned from many different sites, so google and nodejs docs, https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/

Answer (score 0):

```
function broadcast(message, sender) {
    MYVAR2 = message;
     console.log(MYVAR2);
     sender.broadcast.emit('updateHeader',MYVAR2); //Replace socket by sender here
}
```